# Android : style not getting applied to custom view

Tags: android

I have a custom compound view with xml as :

```
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/va_footer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_load_older_results"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pgbr_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</merge>
```

As I expected the background attribute gets ignored as it's specified on a merge tag.
Next I declare an attribute for my view in attrs.xml as

```
<declare-styleable name="SitesFooter">
    <attr name="sitesFooterStyle" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

and the corresponding style in styles.xml as :

```
<style name="sitesFooterStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/card_background</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/card_padding</item>
</style>
```

In the constructor of my custom SitesFooter, I apply this attribute using the defStyle parameter:

```
public SitesFooter( Context context )
{
    this( context, null, R.attr.sitesFooterStyle );
}

public SitesFooter( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
{
    this( context, attrs, R.attr.sitesFooterStyle );
}

public SitesFooter( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle )
{
    super( context, attrs, defStyle );
    // inflate other views.
}
```

But the style just doesn't get applied. The view is not inflated from XML, so I cannot use the style attribute.

I have applied styles this way in the past successfully, but now it just isn't working. Any ideas why?